# Mysql update from a join query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I have a table user_settings which references the user table to save some settings. But I decided to use the settings in a column in the user table.. All good, but now all my settings are in a separate table, and I'm trying to find a query to "import" the user_settings fields into the "setting" column in the user table.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE USER 
SET setting=settings.value
JOIN USER_SETTINGS 
  ON USER_SETTINGS.USER_ID = USER.ID
```

Having a hard time figuring this out, could someone give me a hand?

Comment: Provide sample input data and desired results.  "Some settings" suggests that your code is not representative, because it only sets one value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, you just have your `join` and `set` clauses in the wrong order:

```
UPDATE USER 
JOIN   USER_SETTINGS 
ON     USER_SETTINGS.USER_ID = USER.ID 
SET    setting=settings.value
```